# Specflow could not detect my tests VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit, mstest, specflow

I have been trying since long but no success yet. I created fresh unit test project and added the following :

Packages :

```
Nunit - 3.10.0
Nunit3TestAdapter - 3.11.0
SpecFlow - 2.3.2
SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic - 1.3.1
```

App.Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow"
             type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

**I tried with Nunit as well for above config.**

Also added specflow default feature file and step definition file. But still VS 2017 can not detect any of my tests.

always getting as output :  NUnit couldn't find any tests in ....

**I have already installed Specflow for Visual Studio 2017.**

Comment: We have examples for the different test runners available here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/BowlingKata
I would suggest you compare your project with these. Be aware that they are for the latest version of SpecFlow. SpecFlow 2.3.2 is really old.

Comment: Especially if you have the latest SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio. It defaults to using MSBuild generation for the feature.cs files, instead of the custom tool generation that v2.3 uses. Try `Tools` -> `Options` -> `SpecFlow` and set `Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool` to `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in `Specflow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` Version=2.3.2

A workaround is to edit your .csproj and add a section after `AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject`.

```
<Target Name="AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(SpecFlowGeneratedFiles)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<!-- Workaround Specflow 2.3 MSBuild bug. SpecFlowGeneratedFiles is not set if UpdateFeatureFilesInProject is up-to-date
   causing tests not to be discovered, as they are not included in the project -->
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="**/*.feature.cs" Exclude="@(SpecFlowGeneratedFiles)">
    <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```